# Sitecore BrightCove Installation Issue

Tags: import, installation, sitecore, brightcove, sitecore7

On Installing Brightcove on Sitecore,Import action is not seen and the templates from bright cove is also not seen as per the installation document.

Details are as below:

Sitecore Installed: Sitecore 7.1 rev. 130926.exe

Packages Installed: 
Sitecore Media Framework 1.2 rev. 131220.zip
Sitecore Media Framework Brightcove Edition 1.2 rev. 131220.zip

Below is the screen shot after installation  [image]

Any Idea on why I am not able to see these??

Comment: What are you expecting to see? You need to add an account.

Comment: Ideally upon installation under media framework other items like Media Content,Settings etc get added by default.I tried adding them manually .But here  the main problem is I dont see a Import Icon under Media Framework ribbon.So I guess there is some problem with the package.

Comment: The module is support by Sitecore so I would submit a support ticket directly to them.

Comment: Thanks Mark...Will send out a support request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an account before you see any of those things. The process of adding an account is in chapter 3 of the administrators guide.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select item  /sitecore/media library/Media Framework/Accounts
2. Through insert option click Brightcove Account
3. In popup window give the appropriate name or use default name
4. In the created brightcove account item set the following fields (Publisher Id, Read Token, Write Token)

Now under Media Framework ribbon you can do Import, Cleanup, Export. 
But you can do Import and Cleanup if Brightcove account item or items under this account are selected, in other case, these two buttons will be disabled.